# Nunit Test Dependent Commits - By ID

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, xunit

I have a method that does two commits - here is a simplified version of it:

```
    public void methodA(objectA objA, List<objectB> objB) 
    {
         _repoA.AddAsync(objA);
         var id = _repoA.SaveChanges();
         if(id > 0) {
            foreach (var ob in objB)
            {
              ob.objAId = id;
              _repoB.AddRange(ob);
            }
           _repoB.SaveChanges();
         }
   }
```

How do I get/set the `id` in my unit test to see if my list's `objAId` is set and that it actually contains two object - right now as I cannot set/get `id` in first commit my test fails:

```
[Fact]
    public async void test()
    {
        var objA = new ObjA(null);
        var objB = new List<ObjB>
        {
           new ObjB(null, null, "Test"),
           new ObjB(null, null, "Test2")
        });

        var result = await _sut.methodA(objA, objB);

        Assert.NotNull(result);
        _mockFieldRepository.Verify(x => x.InsertAsync(It.IsAny<MyObjectA>()), Times.Once);
        _mockFieldOptionRepository.Verify(x => x.InsertAsync(It.IsAny<MyObjectB>()), Times.Once); //fails here
        _mockFieldOptionRepository.Verify(x => x.InsertAsync(It.Is<MyObjectB>(p => p.Id > 0 && p.objAId == objA.Id))); //fails here

    }
```

Comment: You don't appear to be mocking the SaveChanges method before the test (you are only verifying it after the test), but if you did, you could use .Callback(...) to set the id.

Comment: Hi Neil, can you please post an example of what you mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE: I have to guess at some of your test setup and interfaces being mocked, so my answer may not be completely correct.**

If we take your original code, there appears to be no Setup mocks to configure what the code is expecting to happen.  You are simply using Verify to make sure that some things DID happen.

So, the first thing we need to do is configure mock so that implied mocks are errors, and also Setup the expectations.

```
_mockFieldRepository = new Mock<IFieldRepository>(MockBehaviour.Strict);
```

You will now find that you get test errors because SaveChanges and AddRange are not Setup. This is good.  So add Setups for them too.

```
_mockFieldRepository.Setup(x => x.SaveChanges();
_mockFieldRepository.Setup(x => x.AddRange(It.IsAny<MyObjectA>());
_mockFieldRepository.Setup(x => x.InsertAsync(It.IsAny<MyObjectA>()));
_mockFieldOptionRepository.Setup(x => x.InsertAsync(It.IsAny<MyObjectB>()));
_mockFieldOptionRepository.Setup(x => x.InsertAsync(It.Is<MyObjectB>(p => p.Id > 0 && p.objAId == objA.Id)));
```

It's a good idea to use It.Is<> during setup, or for simple parameters (integers, strings etc), just pass the expected value, rather than It.Is.

In my opinion, the validation is not great, because It.IsAny<>() means, you don't care how that function is being called, so you should use It.Is (like the 3rd setup) to make 100% certain that the parameters you expect to be passed to the method ARE the parameters you do get.